# How can I get this function to return value retrieved using jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to return dynamic loaded content. I thought this was the way to do it, but the function returns blank. What do I need to do in order to set `htmlCode` with the html code retrieved from `jQuery.ajax`?

```
  // Get directory listing
  function getHTML(instance, current_path, dir) {
    var htmlCode = '';

      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/jquery.php",
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {instance: instance, current_path: current_path, dir: dir},
          success: function(html){
              htmlCode = html;
          },
          error: function(e) {
            htmlCode = '[Error] ' + e;
          }
      });

      return htmlCode;
  }
```

Comment: What version? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for examples

Comment: It's the latest version - 1.4 I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the ajax request takes some time to get the html and your return statement fires before the html is ready. Javascript code execution does not wait for your html to return. You can actually see this by removing the return and putting two alerts. Put one `alert` inside the success event and one where you have put your return statement. The second `alert` would alert before. So, even though your html is fetched, it is never actually returned successfully to the calling function because the return statement already fired by the time html is ready.

You can use a `callback` if you strictly want the function `getHtml()` to return (well actually `call back`) the html as an output, or else you can use the way suggested by Nick.

Here is how to use a callback:-

```
function getHTML(instance, current_path, dir,callback) 
{
   var htmlCode = '';

  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/jquery.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {instance: instance, current_path: current_path, dir: dir},
      success: function(html){

         callback(html); //instead of a return

      },
      error: function(e) {
        htmlCode = '[Error] ' + e;
      }
  });
```

}

Call the function like this -

```
getHTML(instance, current_path, dir,
    function(html)
    {
        //Write code to use the html here - this will run when the getHTML() function does callback with the output html
    }
);
```

Note the `callback` parameter in the function definition getHTML(instance, current_path, dir,callback) and the corresponding `function(html){}` part in the called function.

This way, you actually define:-

- the called function to `call back` the caller function when the output is ready
- and the caller function to do something when it receives the `call back`.

Comment: 2 things here, your syntax is off for the callback style, and there's no need to create an anonymous function for your example, you can pass the function reference directly :)

Comment: sorry I didn't exactly get what you are saying. Where is the syntax error?

Comment: @sandeepan - `function(html))` should be `function(html)` :)

Comment: @Nick, I read somewhere that "Javascript is a ____ language. The code execution does not stop for an asynchronous process to return". I don't remember what was in that _____. Do you know?

Comment: @sandeepan - not sure what word you'd put in that exact phrase, "synchronous" I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

It's an asynchronous operation, so you can't really return like this...not without making the request synchronous (`async: true` option), but I advise against this...since it locks up the browser for the duration of the request.  You can't return because the `success` callback, when asynchronous, doesn't happen until *later* after the request runs, so your `htmlCode = html;` code simply hasn't run yet.

It's a better approach to call what's needed from your `success` callback once you have the data ready, for example:

```
success: function(html){
  doSomethingWithHtml(html);
},
```

or more succinctly for that specific one-liner case:

```
success: doSomethingWithHtml,
```

Comment: I was applying the the html in the success callback. But since I need to retrieve different HTML, I was hoping to save some code by creating only one general function, thus avoid having multiple and almost identical code / functions. The `instance` variable decides what HTML is returned from `jquery.php`.

Comment: @Steven - It sounds like you can use a general function and use it as your `success` then, you could even pass it to `$.ajaxSetup({ success: generalFunction });` to not repeat that on a given page.