# jquery json populate table

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to populate a table with jQuery, but I'm getting caught out by Ajax's asychronisity and not sure how to work it so that things happen in order. There is a main loop over provisioning id's. For each loop I do a JSON call and population of pre-created table. But it seems like the initial loop ticks over before the JSON stuff is done.

```
function getEntityListingsForProvisioning(oArg) {
    var user_id = oArg.user_id || parseInt(0) //zero gets nothing
    var entity = oArg.entity || "products";
    var provisioning_id_list = oArg.provisioning_id;
    var detailLinkClass = oArg.detailLinkClass || "productDetailLink"
    var retDiv = oArg.retDiv || "divResult"

    var provIdArray = provisioning_id_list.split(","); // e.g. ['39', '40']

    $("#" + retDiv).fadeIn('slow').html('');

        // create a table; we'll populate the rows later

    var x = "<table><tr>";
    for(var i=0; i<provIdArray.length; i++) {
        provid = provIdArray[i];
        x += "<td id='td_" + provid + "'>"; 
        x += "<table class='searchPod' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' id='tbl_" + provid + "'>";
        x += "</table></td>";
    }
    x += "</tr></table>";
    $("#" + retDiv).html(x)


    //loop through provisioning id's and get same list of products for each

    for(var j=0; j<provIdArray.length; j++) {
        var y = '';
        provisioning_id = provIdArray[j];

    // get JSON recordset. PROBLEM. I think this isn't getting finished before the main loop ticks over again.
        $.getJSON("/cfcs/main.cfc?method=getProductListings&returnformat=json&queryformat=column", {"user_id":user_id,"short":true}, function(res,code) {
            var v_listing_class = "listingCaption";
            var v_object_type = "ajax";
            var v_onclick = 'return hs.htmlExpand(this,{objectType:"ajax"})';
            var listings_noresults = "<div class='messageSuccess'><b>No records found!</b><br>Use the left-hand menu to add new records.<br>You can return here any time by clicking the Edit Provisioning link</div>";

            if(res && res.ROWCOUNT > 0)
            {
                for(var k=0; k<res.ROWCOUNT; k++)  
                {                   
                    y += "<tr>"
                    y += "<td style='width:10px' valign='middle'><input type='button' value='Use' class='btnSelProduct' id='" + provisioning_id + "^" + res.DATA.RECORD_ID[k] + "^" + entity + "^" + "'></td>"
                    y += "<td style='width:70px' valign='middle'>"
                    y += "<img id='img_" + res.DATA.RECORD_ID[k] + "' src='http://localhost/chinabuy-new/images/website/users/products/images/" + res.DATA.USER_ID[k] + "/" + res.DATA.RECORD_ID[k] + "/" + res.DATA.IMAGE1[k] + "' width='58' height='40'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" 
                    y += "</td>"
                    y += "<td>"
                    y += "<span class='listingText'>" + res.DATA.PRODUCT_NAME[k] + "</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    y += "<span class='listingText'>" + res.DATA.MODEL_NUMBER[k] + "</span>"
                    y += "</td></tr>"
                    $("#tbl_" + provisioning_id).html(y);
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: See if this [jquery Plugin - populateTable()](http://github.com/RaphaelDDL/jquery.populateTable) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

you can see a working solution to a callback related problem in [How can I get this function to return value retrieved using jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695926/how-can-i-get-this-function-to-return-value-retrieved-using-jquery-ajax/3695940#3695940)

but you will have to manipulate your solution from that

I also recommend you to instead collect all the ids you want and then do a single ajax request if that is possible in your case. Every ajax call makes an http request and thus multiple delays.