# Queuing optional AJAX/function calls in jQuery ($.Deferred)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm looking to queue an arbitrary number of possibly optional function calls in JavaScript/jQuery. For example, I may need to ensure the user is authenticated and a cookie is set before running a second (or third, fourth, etc.) function or AJAX call.

I looked into doing this with the recently added jQuery.Deferred, but found that it doesn't matter what order the calls are fired in (true async style). Also, I read that once a Deferred instance has been resolved, it's not possible to un-resolve it.

Here's where I'm at with this at the moment. Initially, I was thinking of setting the Deferred instance to resolved, then un-resolving it if an optional function came up in the stack.

```
var d = $.Deferred(),
    chained = d,
    d.resolve(),
    div = extra.find( "div:first" );

if ( extra.attr( "requires-auth" ) != undefined && !config.user_is_authenticated )
  chained = chained.pipe( authenticate );

if ( div.length )
  chained = chained.pipe( prepareExtra( div ) );

// When the two optional methods are resolved, show the content
chained.done( function() {
  extra.fadeIn( 500 )
} );
```

My question is, what is the best way to queue (0 to N) AJAX calls in pure JavaScript/jQuery? (without using plug-ins).

Tak!

**Edit 2: SOLVED!**
Here's some working examples of this, one w/o AJAX and one with:
https://gist.github.com/1021429
https://gist.github.com/1021435

Comment: Why are you immediately resolving `d` in line 3?

Comment: The thought was, if I didn't immediately resolve d then it would never be done. If chained never received any more functions, then .done would still fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try resolving your initial Deferred as the very last thing:

```
var d = $.Deferred(),
    chained = d;

// optionally chain callbacks with chained = chained.pipe
if (condition) {
    chained = chained.pipe(function () {
        return $.ajax({...}); // Must return a new Promise
    });
}

chained.done(function () {
    // all chains should be processed now
});

d.resolve(); // finally, resolve the initial Deferred
```

Comment: This fired the .done function right a-way, instead of holding off for chained to complete.

Comment: Yes, but you need to return new Promises in your chain functions. Updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Even with promises unique being returned by each function, it would still be asyncronous, no? As far as I understand, it wouldn't halt execution while running the first method, wait for the response and then try the 2nd. I could be wrong on that, but it doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: I need to see how your functions are implemented. They need to be async for this to work. It would be helpful if you pasted more of your code.

Comment: For example, does `prepareExtra( div )` actually do synchronous processing and return right away? It should instead be returning a new Promise and deferring execution until the previous Deferred in the chain is resolved.

Comment: This is a summarized, untested version of it I ripped out of our main module: https://gist.github.com/1017139 - I've gotta say, my head is spinning with all these promises, deferreds & resolves.

Comment: `pipe` takes functions, not Promises. Please see my gist comment.

Comment: `.pipe()` has been deprecated. Use `.then()` instead (does the same thing).

Comment: I've used this to create a fiddle of an ajax queue with `.done()` using `.then()`: https://jsfiddle.net/pn7jekLw/

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence helper:

https://github.com/michiel/asynchelper-js/blob/master/lib/sequencer.js

I had a similar problem: [jQuery Ajax / .each callback, next 'each' firing before ajax completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462605/jquery-ajax-each-callback-next-each-firing-before-ajax-completed)

Comment: Gave this a shot, both the 5 line option and the full library on Github. Neither seemed to do the trick, but I may not be understanding it properly. How would I feed arguments to the functions I'm sequencing? And why is the function(callback) and callback(); necessary? (Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 0):

I've handle this in the past by having an ajax call return the other scripts. To me, that is the best solution.

However, you wanted a pure js approach so I'll give that a shot.

```
var ScriptQueue = {
    scripts: [],
    readyToProcess: false,
    timer: null,
    stopTimer: function() {
        clearTimeout(ScriptQueue.timer);
        ScriptQueue.timer = null;
    },
    queue: function(functionToQueue) {
        ScriptQueue.stopTimer();
        ScriptQueue.scripts.push(functionToQueue);
        ScriptQueue.processNext();
    }, 
    processNext: function() {
       if (!readyToProcess || ScriptQueue.scripts.length == 0) {
           ScriptQueue.timer = setTimeout(ScriptQueue.processNext, 30000); // try again in 30 sec
       } else {
           ScriptQueue.stopTimer();
           var _function = ScriptQueue.scripts.shift();
           _function.call();
           ScriptQueue.processNext();
       }
    }
}

$(function(){

    // queue some stuff

    $('a').each(function() {
        ScriptQueue.queue(function() {
            console.info("running some link action");
        } );
    });

    // authorization
    $.ajax({
        url: yourURL
        success: function(data) {
           if (data == "correct response") {
               ScriptQueue.readyToProcess = true;
               ScriptQueue.processNext();
           }
        }
    })


});
```

I have no idea if this works (not tested) but I wanted to suggest a possible alternative to the `Deferred` solution (which looks promising).  Maybe it will lead to further discuss and maybe ignored.

Comment: I just may give this a shot when I find some time in the next few days! Thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) should work nicely for this:

```
var q = [];
function queue(promise, callback) {
    var ready = $.when.apply($, q); // resolves when all current elements 
                                   // of the queue have resolved
    q.push(promise);
    ready.done(function() {
        q.shift();
        var arg = Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments);
        callback.call(promise, arg);
    });
}
```

Comment: This seemed like a good way to go, but I was a bit confused by the implementation. How would I push functions to the q, and how/when do you run the queue function?

Comment: You use it like this: `queue($.get(url), function() { /* process AJAX response */ })`. This will get the promise object returned by $.get, push it into the queue, create a new promise object which is resolved when everything in the queue is resolved, and call the callback when that new promise is resolved. So, you use `queue` on a promise/deferred and a callback, and the callback will fire when both the promise and all other promises passed earlier to `queue` have resolved (though this only works if they resolved successfully).

Comment: I may have missed something but I'm not sure I see how this would work. I created a jsFiddle for test purposes (http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/9HeAh/) and it has an expected problem with this code. Namely, $.when() always looks at what it is passed and if it does not conform to either a Promise or Deferred, then it creates a new Deferred and resolves it immediately using whatever it was passed. That's what it seems to be doing in line three whenever it gets the array. It resolves immediately passing q as the result.

Comment: @John: Sorry, that should have been `apply`, not `call`. Fixed it.